# Unable to Decrypt a text containg + symbol using AES 256bit Decryption:javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, jsp, encryption, aes

Hi I am not able to decrypt a text containing '+' symbol **inside the JSP page**, I get the following error javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded.

However the code works fine if I run from Eclipse or if I convert the code into Executable Jar.

JARS used :
           local_policy.jar
           US_export_policy.jar

Below is my Java code

```
import java.security.Key;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class Decrypt256bit {

private static Key key;

private static Cipher cipher;

static {
    key = new SecretKeySpec("P@ssw0Rd!@#**&&&P@ssw0Rd!@#**&&&".getBytes(), "AES");
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING","SunJCE");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String encryptData(String plainText) {
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
        return new BASE64Encoder().encode(encrypted);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}

public static String decryptData(String encryptedValue) {
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedValue);
        int maxKeyLen = Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES");
        System.out.println("Length==="+maxKeyLen);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(decordedValue));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You state that you have a problem decrypting but post a code that performs encryption. What do you expect in return?

Comment: apologies here is my code to decrypt

Comment: public static String decryptData(String encryptedValue) {
            try {
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
                byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedValue);
                int maxKeyLen = Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES");
                System.out.println("Length==="+maxKeyLen);
                return new String(cipher.doFinal(decordedValue));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
            }
        }

Comment: Never post code longer than one statement in comments, please edit it into your question.

Comment: The encoding and decoding mostly OK (you should specify explicit `UTF-8` encoding both for `String.getBytes()` and `new String()`). Are you embedding that base64-encoded value into the JSP somehow?

Comment: @OlegEstekhin: The above code is embeded in JSP page.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the Java code but Base64 strings are frequently not valid across a QueryString. You will need to URL Encode your Base64 encoded data if passing the data on the QueryString. Also the plus sign `+` has a semantic meaning within the QueryString. Yet another reason to URL Encode your data (and possible cause of your issue.)

> String data = URLEncoder.encode(myBase64);

Comment: What are you tryingto tell? The above code when converted to a jar will decrypt the string containing + symbol, but its not happening when the same code is included in JSP page.

Comment: @user3473013 Have you actually tried to use this answer? It even supplies the code you needed to use. Indicate what yu don't understand in the above answer.